# How to use Pandas index.insert?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas pivot table that looks like this.

```
               Class1   Class2
Boy    Tall     5         3
       Short    2         4
Girl   Tall     3         3
       Short    3         4
```

To this, I want to add a total row as follows.(without using pivot table 'margins')

```
               Class1   Class2
Boy    Tall     5         3
       Short    2         4
Girl   Tall     3         3
       Short    3         4
Total           13        14
```

I think one way to do this is insert a dummy index (Students) before the current first index (Boy & Girl) and do a groupby (level =0) to calculate the column totals, and remove the dummy index before concat the new sub row with the original dataframe.

```
                         Class1   Class2
Students  Boy    Tall     5         3
                 Short    2         4
          Girl   Tall     3         3
                 Short    3         4
          Total           13        14
```

The code I would write is something like this, but it results in an 'unhashable type' error at the index.insert statement. Another thing I need help with is the method to remove the dummy index. I don't see something like index.remove in the doc.

```
df2 = df
df2.index.insert(0,'Students')   ##  Apparently 'Students' results in 'unhashable type' error
df2 = df2.groupby(level = 0, sort = False).sum()
df2.index.remove(0)            ## This is what I made up...Couldn't find how to remove a particular index from multiindex
pd.concat(df, df2)
```

The documentation says the following, but I couldn't find a good example of an acceptable "item."

```
pandas.Index.insert

Index.insert(loc, item)
  Make new Index inserting new item at location. Follows Python list.append semantics for negative values
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `margins=True`?

Comment: Part of my requirements is to not show the row total. It appears that there is no way to choose only one of the two (ie. row or column total) using pivot_table margins.

Comment: Can you post the data frame before the the pivot so we can recreate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender': ['Boy', 'Boy', 'Girl', 'Girl'], 
                   'height': ['Tall', 'Short'] * 2, 
                   'Class1': [5, 2, 3, 3], 
                   'Class2': [3, 4, 3, 4]}).set_index(['gender', 'height'])

df.ix[('Total', ''), :] = df.sum()

>>> df
               Class1  Class2
gender height                
Boy    Tall       5.0     3.0
       Short      2.0     4.0
Girl   Tall       3.0     3.0
       Short      3.0     4.0
Total            13.0    14.0
```

Comment: The `.ix` method is deprecated since pandas 0.20.0. Use `df.loc[('Total', ''), :] = df.sum()` instead. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `margins=True` and just subset out all the colums except the last one, something like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(data, index = ['gender','height'], 
                   columns = ['class'], margins=True).iloc[:,:-1]
```